# What is the meaning of "one singles out" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> "In the progression of massive hepatic necrosis **one singles out** the
>   stages of yellow atrophy, red atrophy and recovery."

What is the meaning of "one singles out" in this context?

Based on [Merriam Webster dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/single%20out), '**singles out**' means to treat or to speak about. But still nothing understandable for me in this context.

Would you replace 'singles out' with 'treats' here?

> "In the progression of massive hepatic necrosis one **treats** the
>   stages of yellow atrophy, red atrophy and recovery."

Comment: Symptoms can present: X presents [this or that symptom]. A symptom could "stand out", among others. Symptoms are treated. You don't usually see: one treats, but x is treated or a doctor treats a.

Comment: I am sorry, I read your things many times but I really didn't understand your things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In medical English, the best structure is: SVP, subject verb predicate: **The yellow or red atrophy stages are treatable symptoms in the progression of MHN, from which a patient can recover**.

That would be a typical way to say this. That said: You can say: X presents A, B or C symptoms. You would not see: one treats etc. The use of one here does not work even though it is grammatical, it is not the kind of discourse (speech) used in medical texts. Starting a sentence with: in the progression of mhn sounds, for example, like French structure, not like English structure.

**If the sentence you found actually used single out like that, I would say it is not usual at all**. Single out is to choose one thing from among many things: She was singled out from members of her class as the best student. Generally, a person is singled out, a thing is not generally singled out. Except maybe a dog at a dog show: The Boxer was singled out (from all the dogs) as best in class.

Comment: It is a real sentences but I believe that it was written by no native English speakers. Another one that I came across it: "According to Houston classification one singles out 3 types of chronic gastritis: 
nonatrophic, atrophic and specific forms.". In this context it seems that I can replace "one single out" with "there are".

Comment: @Intrigued_by_proliferation Yes, there are would be right.